# Push Down Automanton-Computation

Tags: computer-science, computation-theory, computation, pushdown-automaton

I am trying to understand how PDA works. In the following diagram I understand how transition functions work and how the stack must be updated. But The only question I have is Why the Start state is an accept state as well? while the PDA is for  L = {on1n | n ≥ 0}, means it must not accept an empty string. 
Can some one explain the reason for making the start to be accept state, please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

L = {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ 0}

When n=0, the string is:

0<sup>0</sup>1<sup>0</sup> = zero 0's followed by zero 1's which is the empty string. So according to the definition, the language L does include the empty string.

If it were to not accept the empty string, the definition would be:

L = {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup> | n > 0}

Answer (score 0):

Because the NFA accepts empty strings